# After Git clone all my PHP files text is in one line

Tags: php, git

I had to recover my dev server and cloned the git repo I was working on, however now all files have their text on 1 line only.

This means that all PHP files is useless as many of them have // for my personal info. It's a mess and I am not quite sure what to do.

I understand that Git automatically converts line endings. I am working in a Windows environment and might have had it converted to UNIX/or something else from when I set it up.

Anyway that's done, but is there any way I can fix this?

Comment: Modern editors should recoginze unix line endings by default. What editor do you use?

Comment: I am using Notepad++

Comment: See https://help.github.com/articles/dealing-with-line-endings/#platform-windows

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your installation of git for Windows. Make sure to set it to clone Windows-Style-line-endings (`\r\n`, a.k.a. **CRLF**) and to push Unix-Style-line-endings (`\n`, a.k.a. **LF**). This to prevent your current problem from happening again.

To solve your problem now, open the file in a Notepad / IDE and
replace "\n" by "\r\n". Actually, modern editors should not have a problem
in displaying your text.